# Changing text inside of a dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the text inside of an element for dynamically created elements. i = 2 because that's  Why is it not working?

```js
var loanName = function() {
 for(var t=1; t < i; t++) {
  $('body').on('keyup', '.loanNameV'+t, function () {
   var loanN = $('.loanNameV'+t).val();
   $('.nameLoan'+t).text(loanN);
  });
 }
};
```

Comment: How does the HTML look like? Instead of binding events in a loop you can use *attribute starts with* selector `^=[..]`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: Could you please provide your full html and script code so I can help you

Answer (score 2):

```
$('body').on('keyup', '[class^="loanNameV"]', function () {
         var numbesideclass = ($(this).attr('class').split('loanNameV'))[1];
         var loanN = $(this).val();
         $('.nameLoan'+numbesideclass).text(loanN);
});
```

Note: this code will work if you don't have another class for loanNameV elements like  class="loanNameV1 anotherclass anotherclass" in this case this code will not work as expected